# Multiple nested drop down form - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dropdown, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

i have two models. Post and catogory. I just want to add a few category to post.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories 
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

I want to add drop down field in the views to add category to post.
You can think it is easy but i want use button "ADD CATEGORY" with will create new filed with another drop down category field. I was trying to use cocoon but in the rendered form, object is category not post.

_form.html.haml

```
...
= f.fields_for :category do |i|
  = render 'category_fields', f: i
  .links.right
    %br
  = link_to_add_association 'add category', f, :category, class: 'waves-effect waves-light btn-small form-submit'

...
```

_category_fields.html.haml

```
= f.label :categories
= f.select :categories
```

How i can reffer to parent object? I have to use new jQuery code?

[There is image what a feature i want to get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wyao.jpg)

Comment: are you trying to use https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon ?

Comment: Very unclear what is working and what is not, and your code seems very incomplete. You should at least write `f.fields_for :categories` and add  `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the model?

Answer (score 0):

tried this?
and then user cocoon again

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
end
```

Comment: ofc, when i  use f.label f.object in _category_fileds.html.haml then output is category obj. i want u refer to post object in rendered form